# jQuery bind click

Tags: jquery, click, bind

I have the following situation:

In a html page i have a dynamically generated button, similar to:

```
<div id='myButton'></div>
```

This html page includes a script (e.g., A.js), that handles most of the functionality of the site, and in this script the button is being bound to an handler:

```
$("#myButton").bind("click", function(){
foo();
});
```

So far its simple. Now, only in a particular situation, i need the same button to execute a second function. This has to be done through another script, dynamically generated and injected inside the html site. So the html will look similar to this:

```
<script type=text/javascript src=A.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
//Dynamically generated script
</script>
```

I do not want to override the previous function, i still need that to be executed, but also i need this function to be executed before the first one. And the way scripts are included on the site cannot be changed.

So, I have written the following (inside the second script tag):

```
    $("#myButton").bind("click",
     function(){
          bar(); // I still want foo() to be executed but after this is executed first. 
});
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Note that i do not have control on how scripts  are included on my site. Altering that order is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can still have more bindings to the same event

> http://jsbin.com/iyewu5/edit

they will be fired sorted by what was the first in the code

so you can have:

```
$("#myButton").bind("click", function() { foo(); });
```

and in other script

```
$("#myButton").bind("click", function() { bar(); });
```

this will act as

```
$("#myButton").bind("click", function() { foo(); bar(); });
```

as long as you place them under `$(document).ready( function() {});`

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot control how the event is bound in A.js. This is done by the CMS. I could just add the new click binding, and need to find a way to execute this click first before the one added by the cms.

Comment: it's a matter of what is first, just swap the position... of tell us what are you exactly trying to accomplish with live code for a better help.

Answer (score 0):

why not just combine bolt foo,bar into that function..

```
$("#myButton").bind("click", function(){
 bar();
 foo();
});
```

or you may implement the foo() as callback function.

Comment: Yes, but i am not adding the foo(), its has been added by the system (the CMS in this case) and i cannot alter that behavior!